# Java program....new to programming

Tags: java

this is my first question here, so here it goes, I have tried this for ages with no luck, I am new to Java (studying it) and I have an assignment and I cant get this to work (only the first part works)...thanks in advanced for any help you can give me! :)

**Write a program to read in a non-specified number of Employee Salaries from the user. After each Employee Salary is entered the program should then calculate the Bonus for each employee. The bonus is to be calculated as a percentage of the Salary, according to the table shown below:

Salary  Bonus Rate

Less than €10,000   5% 
Between €10,000 and less than €20,000   10% 
Between €20,000 and less than €30,000   15% 
€30,000 or more 20%

The Program should output the Bonus Rate, Bonus Amount, and Total Salary for each Employee after the salary is entered.

When the user has entered the details for all employees, the program should then output the following: 
Overall Total Bonuses paid 
Overall Total Salaries paid (including bonuses) 
Average Bonus

Your program should let the user indicate that they have finished entering results. 
Add extra checks to your program so that negative figures are rejected by the program along with a suitable error message.

Test your program thoroughly, so that it works under all possible conditions. 
Input/Output from the program should be attractively displayed on the screen.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


            class Salary
            {
             public static void main (String args [])
               {
                 Scanner myInput = new Scanner (System.in);

                  double salary =0, bonusRate =0, bonusAmount=0, salaryTotal=0,                           totalBonus=0, averageBonus=0, totalSalaries=0;
    int salaryCounter=0;
    char response;

    do
    {

        System.out.println("Press a to enter a salary or press 'q' to quit");
        response=myInput.next().charAt(0);


        switch(response)
        {
            case 'a':

            do
            {

            System.out.println("Enter employee salary or press q to quit");
            salary = myInput.nextDouble();

                if (salary <=0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry please enter Salary again ");
                }

                 else if (salary >0 && salary <=10000)
                {
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("The bonus rate is 5%");
                    bonusRate = salary * .05;
                    System.out.println("The bonus is " + bonusRate);
                    salaryTotal= salary + bonusRate;
                    System.out.println("The Total salary " + salaryTotal);
                    salaryCounter=salaryCounter+1;
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");

                }
                else if (salary >10000 && salary <=20000)
                {
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("The bonus rate is 10%");
                    bonusRate = salary * .10;
                    System.out.println("The bonus is " + bonusRate);
                    salaryTotal= salary + bonusRate;
                    System.out.println("The Total salary " + salaryTotal);
                    salaryCounter=salaryCounter+1;
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");

                }
                else if (salary >20000 && salary <=30000)
                {
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("The bonus rate is 15%");
                    bonusRate = salary * .15;
                    System.out.println("The bonus is " + bonusRate);
                    salaryTotal= salary + bonusRate;
                    System.out.println("The Total salary " + salaryTotal);
                    salaryCounter=salaryCounter+1;
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");


                }
                else if (salary >30000)
                {
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("The bonus rate is 20%");
                    bonusRate = salary * .20;
                    System.out.println("The bonus is " + bonusRate);
                    salaryTotal= salary + bonusRate;
                    System.out.println("The Total salary " + salaryTotal);
                    salaryCounter=salaryCounter+1;
                    System.out.println("*************************************************************");


                }
                //else
                //{  //do i need to get rid of this?

                //  System.out.println("");
                //}

            }while(salary <=0);{

                break;

                }case 'q':

                salaryCounter = salaryCounter+1;
                bonusAmount= salary*bonusRate;
                salaryTotal=salary+bonusAmount;
                totalBonus=totalBonus+bonusAmount;
                totalSalaries=totalSalaries+salaryTotal;
                averageBonus=totalBonus*salaryCounter;


                System.out.printf("The Total Salaries paid including Bonus is %.2f " , totalSalaries);
                System.out.println("Euro");
                System.out.printf("The Total of Bonuses paid is %.2f ", totalBonus);
                System.out.println("Euro");
                System.out.printf("The Total of Average Bonuses paid is %.2f ", averageBonus);
                System.out.println("Euro");

                break;


        }//end do


 //end switch

        }while (response != 'q');{
        //do while loop to repeat until 'q' is entered.


} //end do while loop


    }//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Where? What exactly is not working? Please briefly state the goal rather than give us your entire homework prompt. "Only the first part works" is very broad. What constitutes as the "first part?"

Comment: Side note: You are repeating a lot of code unnccessarily, you can instead just change variable values based on salary and then only use one print for all salaries.

Comment: sorry, you're right, the salaryCounter is not taking all the salaries entered and at the end i am not getting the overall total bonus paid or the total salaries paid or the average bonus...i was surprised one time i got an "infinite" answer so i am pretty sure i am placing something in the wrong way....the first part calculates (so far correctly the bonus rate, the bonus amount and total salary)

Comment: Look at how do-while loops work. There should only be one block of code (encapsulated in curly brackets: `{ //code ... }`) But you have two. One after `do`, and one after `while`.

Comment: thank you Mitch Talmadge i will change this asap!

Comment: thank you user3284549 much appreciated you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can create two different files for your requirements: one pojo class containing the attributes of the employee and second main app where the user interacts with the program.

Salary.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class Salary {
    private static int count = 0;
    private int empId;
    private double salary;
    private int bonusRate;
    private double bonusAmount;
    private double totalSalary;

    //Getters and Setters
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public double getTotalSalary() {
        return totalSalary;
    }
    public void setTotalSalary(double totalSalary) {
        this.totalSalary = totalSalary;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public int getBonusRate() {
        return bonusRate;
    }
    public void setBonusRate(int bonusRate) {
        this.bonusRate = bonusRate;
    }
    public double getBonusAmount() {
        return bonusAmount;
    }
    public void setBonusAmount(double bonusAmount) {
        this.bonusAmount = bonusAmount;
    }

    //Constructors
    public Salary(int empId, double salary, int bonusRate, double bonusAmount,
            double totalSalary) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.bonusRate = bonusRate;
        this.bonusAmount = bonusAmount;
        this.totalSalary = totalSalary;
    }
    public Salary() {
        super();
        count = count + 1;
        this.empId = count;
    }

    //toString
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Salary [empId=" + empId + ", salary=" + salary + ", bonusRate="
                + bonusRate + ", bonusAmount=" + bonusAmount + ", totalSalary="
                + totalSalary + "]";
    }

    //calculation function
    public void calculateBonus(){
        double bonus;
        if(this.getSalary()<10000){
            this.setBonusRate(5);
            bonus = this.getSalary() + 0.05*(this.getSalary());
        }else if(this.getSalary()<20000){
            this.setBonusRate(10);
            bonus = this.getSalary() + 0.10*(this.getSalary());
        }else if(this.getSalary()<30000){
            this.setBonusRate(15);
            bonus = this.getSalary() + 0.15*(this.getSalary());
        }else{
            this.setBonusRate(20);
            bonus = this.getSalary() + 0.20*(this.getSalary());
        }
        this.setBonusAmount(bonus);
        this.setTotalSalary(this.getSalary() + bonus);
    }
}
```

MainApp.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Salary> salaries = new ArrayList<Salary>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String op = "y";
        do {
            Salary salary = new Salary();
            System.out.println("Please Enter Salary for User "
                    + salary.getEmpId() + " :");
            salary.setSalary(sc.nextDouble());
            salary.calculateBonus();
            System.out.println(salary);
            salaries.add(salary);
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more salaries: ");
            op = sc.next();
        } while (op.equals("y"));
        double totalSalaries = 0;
        double totalBonus = 0;
        double averageBonus = 0;
        int numberOfSalaries = 0;
        for (Salary salary : salaries) {
            System.out.println("Empid: " + salary.getEmpId() + " Salary: "
                    + salary.getSalary() + " Bonus Rate: "
                    + salary.getBonusRate() + " Bonus Amount: "
                    + salary.getBonusAmount() + " Total Salary: "
                    + salary.getTotalSalary());
            totalSalaries = totalSalaries + salary.getTotalSalary();
            totalBonus = totalBonus + salary.getBonusAmount();
            numberOfSalaries = numberOfSalaries + 1;
        }
        averageBonus = totalBonus / numberOfSalaries;
        System.out.println("Total Salaries for all employees: " + totalSalaries
                + " Total Bonuses: " + totalBonus
                + " Average Bonuses for all employees: " + averageBonus);
    }
}
```

The code shall suffice your requirements.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I did a lot of googling and looking around trying to get the second part of this assignment working, but nothing seemed to work, i will use all the help i got here! thanks again much appreciated!